# c++ operator= method for const references

Tags: c++

I am writing class with a const reference like this:

```
class B;

class foo {
  const B& b;

  foo(const B& newb): b(newb) { }

  void operator=(const foo & foo2) {
      // This does not work
      foo.b = foo2.b;
  }   
};
```

I am trying to define a working operator= Obviously = does not work since I am not allowd to change a const reference. This there a way to let a reference point to another object?

If b is not const c++ will provide me with a working operator=. If I define one member as const cl will spit out:

warning C4512: 'foo' : assignment operator could not be generated

Comment: Did you mean to write something like `b = foo2.b;`?

Comment: `operator=` is not a copy constructor, it's operator=. A copy constructor takes the form of `Class(const Class&)`.

Comment: I think this form of construction is very dangerous: this provides a simple way to produce "dangling references". If `newb` comes from a temporary, then the temporary is destroyed when the constructor finishes, and `b` will be referencing garbage.

Comment: Yes I meant b=foo2.b;

I know that this is dangerous.

Comment: you might be looking for swap, as an http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/swap/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "rebind."  As in "is it possible to rebind a reference?"  The answer is "no, references are defined as not being rebindable."  But you can use a pointer and change what it points to:

```
class B;

class foo {
    B* b;

    foo(const B& newb)
    {
        b = &newb;
    }

    void operator=(const foo& foo2)
    {
        b = &foo2.b;
    }   
};
```

However, this risks dangling pointers if the object being assigned to outlives the object used for the assignment (same problem for the constructor, by the way).  There's a good chance that you don't need references or pointers at all:

```
class B;

class foo {
    B b;

    foo(const B& newb): b(newb) { }

    void operator=(const foo& foo2)
    {
        b = foo2.b;
    }   
};
```

If you do need pointers/references (maybe `B` is a base class) then you'll want to look into smart pointers to handle object lifetime issues.

Comment: B is a *huge* rather large object in this case. And the class should really hold it as reference so if the object changes the changes are visiable too.

Comment: A pointer and reference are fundamentally the same thing in this example, except a reference can't be null; the size of the object doesn't matter in either case.

Comment: @plaisthos:  Also, if you assign over a pointer to a B, you might be overwriting the last pointer to that B, and have a memory leak.  It sounds like it might not take too many lost Bs to be a serious leak.  Seriously consider smart pointers.

Comment: @plaisthos:  A number of programmers coming from Java assume that pointers or references are the only option.  They aren't:  plain objects ("value semantics") are usually enough.  From what you're saying, you have a good reason to use pointers/references.  Since you need rebinding, you need pointers.  Since you probably will have to manage the lifetimes of the various objects, you should look at smart pointers, like boost::share_ptr (a.k.a., std::tr1::share_ptr).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think your code makes any sense.  There is no object called `foo`, so `foo = foo2` is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

No, once a reference is initialized, the object it references cannot be changed. If you need to do that, a pointer is more appropriate.

Comment: I editet my question and hope that it is now understandable what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change which object a reference refers to. Use a pointer in your class instead.